# Inserting data from html to database, query error

Tags: java, sql, database, jsp

Inserting data into database from a html page, I've successfully passed data to a jsp and then a java file, but I'm getting an error when inserting the data into the database.

This is the Query:

```
String ResultQuery = "INSERT INTO Results (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeScore, awayScore)" +
    "VALUES (+HomeTeam+','+AwayTeam+','+HomeScore+','+AwayScore+)";
```

This is the error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '+HomeTeam+','+AwayTeam+','+HomeScore+','+AwayScore+'.
```

Comment: If you copied this directly then you are missing the opening single quote for `+HomeTeam+'` and the closing quote for `'+AwayScore+`

Comment: [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: I recommend you to use parameterized queries rather than using variables directly in query, then you can avoid these type of errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong, if all of this [HomeTeam,AwayTeam,HomeScore,AwayScore] are variables you should rewrite the query in this form:

```
String ResultQuery = "INSERT INTO Results (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeScore, awayScore)" +
    "VALUES ('"+HomeTeam+"','"+AwayTeam+"','"+HomeScore+"','"+AwayScore+"')";
```

but if those not variables you should write in this form:

```
String ResultQuery = "INSERT INTO Results (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeScore, awayScore)" +
    "VALUES ('HomeTeam','AwayTeam','HomeScore','AwayScore')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a single quote (') before your first value and then end of your last value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some quotes - try this:

```
String ResultQuery = "INSERT INTO Results (homeTeam, awayTeam, homeScore, awayScore)" +
"VALUES ("+HomeTeam+"','"+AwayTeam+"','"+HomeScore+"','"+AwayScore+")";
```

(I assumed that `HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore` are variables)

Comment: You are missing the same single quotes.